# Processing table rows in Typescript

Tags: javascript, dom, typescript

I have been trying to convert a JavaScript web form to Typescript, and have been unable to work out how to convert statements involving table rows, such as the following:

```
let body = document.getElementById("selectStackBody");

let rowCount = body.rows.length;

let row = body.insertRow(rowCount);

body.deleteRow(i);
```

I can see how to get the body by doing the following:

```
let body = <HTMLBodyElement>document.getElementById("selectStackBody");
```

but I can't see how to get the right syntax for the rows.

Comment: What's the problem? What errors are being thrown? What have you tried?

Comment: The `HTMLBodyElement` interface does not have a `rows` property. The `HTMLTableSectionElement` interface (which a `tbody` element uses), however, does. If you show the HTML on which you are attempting to run this code, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to do anything TypeScript specific here. Basic DOM syntax can do this for you.

If `document.getElementById("selectStackBody")` gives to the table body node then simply do `body.childNodes.length` to get the number of rows.

Similarly, to append a row, use the DOM syntax to add a child node.

Here's a sample:

```
const body = document.getElementById('selectStackBody')

// Total number of rows
let numberOfRows = body.childNodes.length

// Add a new row
let newRow = document.createElement('tr')
body.appendChild(newRow)

// Remove the first row
body.removeChild(body.childNodes[0])
```